# postgresql how to backup and overwrite specific tables

Tags: postgresql, database-restore

I need to be able to somehow get a set of tables from my dev db into my production db. I've just been creating a dump file from the dev db and using pg_restore on the production db. The problem now is that I need to preserve one table(called users) on the production db while replacing the others

I think I have the dump properly from this command

```
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U <USER> --exclude-table=users* --data-only <DB NAME> > test.dump
```

But I can't get the restore part to work. I tried the following command

```
pg_restore -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h <PROD HOST> -U <USER> -d <DB NAME> -p <PORT> <FILE LOCATION>
```

BUt I get the following errors

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2009; 0 121384 TABLE DATA idx_descs Jason
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] COPY failed for table "idx_descs": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_descs_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY idx_descs, line 1
```

It seems like for the tables I'm trying to overwrite, it is just trying to append the data and running into trouble because there are now duplicate primary keys. Any Ideas how to do this? Thanks

Comment: I run pg_restore with clean and disable triggers options to restore to my existing table with data and get the same error...

Comment: Could you check if there are duplicate records in dev because of a missing constraint?

Comment: What I usually do is to merge the `prod` and `dev` dumps into one (which I test on another testing database). Then stop the access to the prod server for a couple of minutes, import the database (which I have already tested and it proved to be working) and finally restore access to the server. You just need to be careful with the prod data when you're merging your dev data.

Comment: @tftd How to merge two binary dumps?

Comment: @Vlad valid point. I overlooked the part he's talking about binary data..

Comment: @Jayadevan this error occurs because the data that is importing already exists in the table. it should be cleaned preliminary without constraints checking. this what the question about.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to reassign primary keys?

You could try restoring to a temporary table (say for instance, in failing case: idx_desc_temp), then doing something like:

```
with t as ( select * from idx_descs_temp )
insert into idx_descs
    select id + 100000 [or whatever], [other fields] from t;
```

Afterwards you need to reset sequences (if applicable -- fill in sequence name....):

```
select setval( 'idx_descs_id_seq'::regclass, 100000 + [suitable increment]);
```

If you have a large # of tables you could try to automate using the system catalog.

Note though that you also have to renumber foreign key refs. Possibly less pain would be to move data in production db first. If you are using an ORM, you could also automate via application APIs.